# Criar uma entidade que some valores de objetos de outras entidades API .NET c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp-net-core

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante em .NET e estou com uma dúvida.
Criei uma API que contém duas entidades: Despesa e Receita, e as duas entidades possuem campos de atributo valor do tipo decimal.
Qual a melhor maneira de se criar uma terceira entidade onde eu possa somar os valores dessas entidades e implantar as regras de negócio da API? Já tentei colocando dentro do repository, mas parece que não é a melhor maneira...

Entidade despesa:

```
public class Despesa : BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual CategoriaDespesa CategoriaDespesa { get; set; }
        public virtual FormaDePagamento FormaDePagamento { get; set; }

        public IList<FluxoDeCaixa> Fluxos { get; set; }
}
```

Entidade Receita:

```
public class Receita : BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual CategoriaReceita CategoriaReceita { get; set; }
        public virtual FormaDePagamento FormaDePagamento { get; set; }

        public IList<FluxoDeCaixa> Fluxos { get; set; }
}
```

Essa é a terceira entidade que criei:

```
public class FluxoDeCaixa : BaseEntity
    {
        public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }

        public long Id_Despesa { get; set; }
        public Despesa Despesa { get; set; }

        public long Id_Receita { get; set; }
        public Receita Receita { get; set; }
}
```

O repositório do fluxo, onde tentei filtrar o nome das categorias e fazer uma soma de acordo com o mês/ano:

```
public decimal ObterValorBruto(int month, int year) 
    {

        decimal total = _context.Receitas.Where(x => x.Data.Month == month)
                                        .Where(x => x.Data.Year == year)
                                        .Where(x => x.CategoriaReceita.Nome == "Venda de produtos")
                                        .Where(x => x.CategoriaReceita.Nome == "Prestação de serviços")
                                        .Sum(x => x.Valor);
        
        return total;
    }
```

Ainda não implementei o service pois não tenho certeza se esses cálculos deveriam ficar lá...

Comment: Olá!

Pelo que parece voce está colocando lógica de negócios na camada de dados. Ainda que façamos uma discussão sobre onde de fato deva estar essa lógica, queria te. perguntar onde voce quer tratar regras de negocio? aplicação ou banco?

Comment: Opa, preciso tratar essas regras na aplicação.

Comment: Entao, ao invés de fazer no repository (ai onde tem o _context), crie uma camada de lógicas de negocios, uma BLL ou qqr outra coisa, retorne o objeto na integra pra la, e la faça as operações de lógica de negócio.

Comment: Deu certo, cara. Muito obrigado, tava com a cabeça cheia e isso nem passou pela cabeça.

Comment: Ótimo! vou colocar isso na resposta e talvez ajude os próximos com dúvidas similares :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como sua necessidade é tratar os dados na camada de aplicação, é importante separar os conceitos e objetivos de cada uma das suas classes.

No seu código onde esta
`public decimal ObterValorBruto(int month, int year)
{

```
    decimal total = _context.Receitas.Where(x => x.Data.Month == month)
                                    .Where(x => x.Data.Year == year)
                                    .Where(x => x.CategoriaReceita.Nome == "Venda de produtos")
                                    .Where(x => x.CategoriaReceita.Nome == "Prestação de serviços")
                                    .Sum(x => x.Valor);
    
    return total;
}`
```

Separe os objetivos, coloque sua lógica de negócio em outro lugar, como uma BLL ou similar